# OneSignal Push Notifications Segmenting users

Tags: android, onesignal

I have created an app in OneSignal.com . Now I need to segment users but i dont know how to do that using android using onesignal as i am new to android.

So How do I segment users in Android OneSignal so that to send push notifications to specific users in that segment.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use tag feature in your onesignal app sdk where in you will tag a student with class 1 like `OneSignal.sendTag("class",1);`  Then in your one signal panel create a segment class1 students and in filter type select "User Tag".

In key type "class" and select equal to in value type 1. then click on save.  now all the students in class == 1 will be included in this segment

Comment: This is simple and clear but, how to to if the tab is multi-value? Following the example above what if I have two children in two different classes? The settaggio api override the first called  one.

Answer (score 2):

You can segment users by creating a new segment on the Segments page with the filters of your choice.

For instance, if you wanted to create a segment that matched all users that were not active in the last 2 days, you could create a segment with the filter "last active is more than 48 hours ago".

You can also create segments with filters based on tags that you assign using SetTags in your app.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Gdeglin .. Still I didn't get .. 

Lets take an example. Suppose I have created a School App In OneSignal. Now if i want to send push notifications to only specific class students suppose only to class 1 students, how would I target them.??? What i need to do to in android app code ?? 
Please explain me in detail.
Thank You.